# FPDF multi cell overlapping

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to export my table as pdf. I am fetching table content via API and than trying to export this as pdf using FPDF library. It is working fine but I need to implement multi cell for this which is not working.

This is how I am trying to implement this.

```
    // Column widths
$w = array(30, 30, 50, 30, 20, 30);
// Data
foreach($data as $value)
{
    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();
    $pdf->MultiCell($w[0],8,$value['firstname'],1, 1);
    $pdf->SetXY($x + $w[0], $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();
    $pdf->MultiCell($w[1],8,$value['lastname'],1, 1);
    $pdf->SetXY($x + $w[1], $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();
    $pdf->MultiCell($w[2],8,$value['companyname'],1, 1);
    $pdf->SetXY($x + $w[2], $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();
    $pdf->MultiCell($w[3],8,$value['shipcity'],1, 1);
    $pdf->SetXY($x + $w[3], $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();
    $pdf->MultiCell($w[4],8,$value['shipstate'],1, 1);
    $pdf->SetXY($x + $w[4], $y);

    $x = $pdf->GetX();
    $y = $pdf->GetY();
    $pdf->MultiCell($w[5],8,$value['shipcountry'],1, 1);
    $pdf->SetXY($x + $w[5], $y);

    $pdf->Ln();
}
// Closing line
$pdf->Cell(array_sum($w),0,'','T');
$pdf->Output($filename, 'F');
```

On first page content is overlapping and all the other pages are almost empty. I have attached an image for this. Can you help me with this ?

First Page
[image: First PDF page]

Second Page
[image: Second PDF Page]

Comment: What is the "extra" data in the company column? Is it part of the company name, the last name or something else? Obviously something is spilling to the 2nd page but without seeing the output of the entire first page it's hard to tell exactly what it is (it looks like possibly a first name). Also, please [edit] your question and include the page definitions you use after starting the PDF.

Comment: You are also using an invalid value as the 5th parameter to the `MultiCell` calls. Valid values for the 5th parameter are L, C, R and J. The number 1 that you are using is not valid.

Comment: It is company data and I want to display the overlapped text on second line but instead it is overlapping the existing text.

Comment: You can try breaking it up with PHP and using `\n` to move to a new line but I'm not sure that is going to work with fPDF and MultiCell.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for this suggestion and time. I will fix this 5th parameter issue. But it is company text which is overlapping and I want to display this on second line instead of next cell. Company name in first row is "Certified Coating Company" and word "company" is displaying in next cell instead of second line in the same cell.

Comment: You might also want to try removing the setting of the X and Y coordinates directly and letting MultiCell take care of it. As the documentation shows, the `\n` should work.

Comment: It was not working automatically so that is why I am trying X and Y coordinates

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include PHP arrays with some sample data so that others may help you more easily.